# Semantic error during if-statement check in program

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

So I have a form that requires the user to put in all info. Only by entering all the info does the information get saved. However a weird little bug has come about.After submitting with no checkbox selected and then switching to yes afterwards (Yes this is intended) as long as a radio-button is selected, data is saved. I don't wish to change the properties of the form my only wish is to fix the semantic error when checking during the if-statements.

```
#Import tkinter to make gui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

#Sets title and creates gui
root = Tk()
root.title("Entry Form")

def changed1(*args):
    if yes.get()=="1":
        no.set('0')
def changed2(*args):
    if no.get()=="1":
        yes.set('0')

#After sumbitting with no selected and then switching to yes afterwards as long as a radiobutton is seletected, data is saved?
def submit(*args): #Realign?
    file = open("data.csv", "a")
    if first.get() != "" and last.get() != "" and option.get() == 'Business' or option.get() == 'Residence' or option.get() == 'Other' and state.get() != "" and yes.get() == '1' or no.get() == '1':
        if yes.get()=='1':
            file.write(last.get().title() + "," + first.get().title() + "," + option.get() + "," + state.get() + '\n')
            printer.set("Data Saved!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Unauthorized", "You must accept terms to continue.")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Incomplete Information", "Please fill out all parts of the form")

#Configures column and row settings and sets padding
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

first = StringVar()
last = StringVar()
option = StringVar()
statevar = StringVar()
printer = StringVar()
yes = StringVar()
no = StringVar()

#Widgets to put in name
firstvar = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=15, textvariable=first)
firstvar.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(N, W))

lastvar = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=15, textvariable=last)
lastvar.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(N, W))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="First Name").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Last Name").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W))

business = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='Business', variable=option, value='Business')
residence = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='Residence', variable=option, value='Residence')
other = ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text='Other', variable=option, value='Other')

business.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
residence.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
other.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

state = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable=statevar, state='readonly')
state.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="State").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)
state['values'] = ('Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachussetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvannia', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming')

#Creates no checkbutton
yesvar = ttk.Checkbutton(mainframe, text='Yes', command=changed1, variable=yes)
yesvar.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=(W, E))

#Creates yes check button
novar = ttk.Checkbutton(mainframe, text='No', command=changed2, variable=no)
novar.grid(column=3, row=5, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Accept Policy").grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=(W))

#Adds a calculate button
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Submit", command=submit).grid(column=3, row=9, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=printer).grid(column=2, row=9, sticky=(E))

root.bind('<Return>', submit)

#Keeps the gui running
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please add the error log as well.

Comment: with complex expressions with `and` and `or`, you should always use parentheses to group sub-expressions.There's a good chance that the order of evaluation is different than what you expect. Spreading the big `if` over multiple lines will also greatly help in readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to test `option` more than once.
Use `if first.get():` instead of `if first.get() != ""`.
You are testing `yes` in the second `if` statement, so remove it from the first one (needed to show different messagebox).

```
# Check required fields
if first.get() and last.get() and option.get() and state.get():
    # Check Constraints before saving
    if yes.get() == '1':
```